# Windows 7 Sleep Problems

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

My desktop's Windows 7 installation was working perfectly but recently I ran into a problem where it would not come out of sleep. The system seems to be running it's just that it won't come out of the sleep state. If I have to guess I would say that it's not recognizing the USB and thus not waking.

I'd say this was a standard problem with Windows not sleeping/hibernating properly, but it was working fine for about a year and stopped working around two weeks ago.

I have hybrid sleep ON and USB selective suspend ON.

Comment: How do you know it won't come out of sleep? Is it possible that it is coming out of sleep, but the graphics driver isn't being woken up? I had a problem where my computer would come out of sleep but the monitor never got a signal. Fixed eventually when AMD finally released a driver that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and also frequently freeze.

**IF YOU GOT ATI**

Solved like that:

Go to  \Local Settings\Application Data\ATI\ACE\Profiles.xml and replace "**x**" by "**X**"

```
<Feature name="CoreClockTarget_0"> 
<Property name="Want_0" value="xxxxx" /> 
<Property name="Want_1" value="XXXXX" /> 
<Property name="Want_2" value="85000" /> 
</Feature> 
<Feature name="MemoryClockTarget_0"> 
<Property name="Want_0" value="xxxxx" /> 
<Property name="Want_1" value="XXXXX" /> 
<Property name="Want_2" value="120000" /> 
</Feature>
```

The problem is due to the powerloss of the ATI devices when it go to sleep mode.
This will adjust the power !

**ELSE I DON'T KNOW ! =)**

Answer (score 0):

What did you install win7 on? Was it an older machine? I had a similar problem on a Win7 beta install on an old HP workstation at home. You may want to update the BIOS. That can help with power management. You can also check to see if the device is on the Win7 compatibility list.

Comment: It's a relatively new system- Intel Core 2 Quad and Intel P45 chipset.  I'll definitely check the BIOS but I'm not sure what would explain the sudden change.